# Why does this code to find factorial only work for a single input?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

For multiple inputs, this shows weird results, eg: for *2, 4, 5* it shows output as *24, 24*.

```
T = int(raw_input())
L = [] 
for i in range(0,T):
num = int(raw_input())
L.append(num)
product = 1
k = 0
for item in L:
    while k < item:
        term = item - k
        product = product * term
        k = k + 1
    print product
```

Comment: Please, fix the code indentation so, we know what the code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the indentation of your first `for` loop. Then initialize `product` and `k` inside the main `for` loop so that they can be reset for each input number. The variable `term` is redundant since you can simply multiply `product` by `k` instead:

```
T = int(raw_input())
L = [] 
for i in range(0,T):
    num = int(raw_input())
    L.append(num)
for item in L:
    k = 1
    product = 1
    while k <= item:
        product = product * k
        k = k + 1
    print product
```

Comment: Why is it wrong to initialize 'product' and 'k' before the for loop ?

Comment: Because they need to be reset for each input number. I've added this explanation to the answer.